# Kubuntu failed to run Davinci Resolve

Tags: kubuntu, amd-graphics, davinci-resolve

I followed the instruction [Ubuntu install DaVinci Resolve](https://www.fosslinux.com/24381/how-to-install-davinci-resolve-on-ubuntu.htm).

When try to launch, it report error:

```
DaVinci REsolve could not find any OpenCL capable GPUs.
Would you like to review and update your Davinci Resolve Hardware Configuration?
```

My machine hardware as:

```
spirit@alpha 
------------ 
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 
Host: RedmiBook 16 
Kernel: 5.8.1-050801-generic 
Uptime: 1 hour, 35 mins 
Packages: 2136 (dpkg) 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
Terminal: /dev/pts/3 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 4500U with Radeon Graphics (6) @ 2.375GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI 02:00.0 Renoir 
Memory: 4635MiB / 15437MiB
```

Where could I set about to solve the problem from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD and Resolve are not the best of friends, but it is doable. Sounds like you've done the Resolve install correctly - the issue here is that it can't see the GPU properly.

First up, you really need to use an offboard GPU. Integrated GPU's in the CPU aren't what Resolve is intended to use.

Next, if your AMD drivers are the latest and greatest already, you may have to rollback one or two versions.

If you are not the latest and greatest version, try upgrading to the next version (not necessarily the latest and greatest release).

You may also glean some further assistance from the Black Magic Design Linux issues discussion thread: https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=56878

Answer (score 0):

You need AMD's proprietary AMDGPU-PRO driver with OpenCL support enabled for DaVinci Resolve.
I don't know if those drivers work with any of AMD's integrated GPUs, they are at least not officially supported. You can try downloading the driver for some recent dedicated AMD GPU, they're all the same. Maybe it works. Just extract the .tar.xz archive, go into it and and run `./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=legacy,rocr`.

The free version of DaVinci Resolve is a pain on Linux anyway because of the extremely limited codec support. But there's a bunch of other great video editing software for Linux: [https://www.slant.co/topics/2073/~best-video-editors-for-linux](https://www.slant.co/topics/2073/%7Ebest-video-editors-for-linux)